# Is $\ln(x)+1$ contractive?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, intuition, holder-spaces, contraction-operator

I am having trouble understanding the definition of a contractive function. The definition is:

Let $(\Bbb R,d)$ be a Metric Space with the standard metric.

Let $A\subseteq X$  (with the same metric as $\Bbb R$)

Let $\,f:A\rightarrow A$ be a function.

$f$ is said to be a contraction on $A$ if there exists some $C\in (0,1)$ such that $\forall x,y\in A$

$d(f(x),f(y))\le C*d(x,y)$

Let $\epsilon>0$

Let $A=[1+\epsilon, + \infty]$

I think $f(x)=\ln(x)+1$ is contractive on $A$ because $\cfrac{d(f(x),f(y))}{d(x,y)}<1,\,\,\forall x,y,\in A$ but at no point is there a fixed point $(f(x)=x)$ $(x\in A$) so it should not be contractive by contrapositive

Comment: $\ln(1+\epsilon)+1 < 1+\epsilon$, which violates that $f$ is a function with domain and range $A = [1+\epsilon,\infty)$. For example, $\ln(1.1)+1 = 1.0953101...$. If you fix this by letting $A = [1,\infty)$ then you will see that $f(1)=1$, and so there is no contradiction, although you will lose the property that $f$ is a contraction.

Comment: Your inequality does not show that $f$ is contractive, since you have chosen $C = 1$. The definition of contractive requires that $0 < C < 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I).If $\epsilon >0$ and $A\subset (1,\infty)$ with $\inf A=1+\epsilon$ then $f$ is not contractive on $A$ because $f$ does not map $A$ into $A.$

For $y>0$ we have $\log (1+y)<y$ so $f(1+y)<1+y$ .  So $f(\inf A)<\inf A.$ Let $v=\frac {1}{2} (\inf A-f(\inf A)).$

Now $f$ is continuous on $\Bbb R^+$ so there exists  $u\in (0,\inf A) $ such that $|x-\inf A|<u\implies |f(x)-f(\inf A)|<v.$ Then $|x-\inf A|<u\implies f(x)<\inf A.$

By definition of  $\inf A,$ there exists $x\in A$ with $\inf A\leq x<u+\inf A,$ and for such $x$ we have $f(x)<\inf A,$ so $x\in A$ but $f(x)\not \in A.$

In particular , $f$ is not a contraction on $A=[1+\epsilon,\infty)$ for any $\epsilon >0$ because $f$ does not map $A$ into $A.$

(II).$f$ is not contractive on  $[1,\infty).$  For $1<y$ there exists $z\in (1,y)$ such that  $$\frac {d(f(y),f(1))}{d(y,1)}= \frac {f(y)-f(1)}{y-1} = f'(z)=1/z>1/y .$$ $$\text {Therefore }\quad  \sup_{1<x< y}  \frac {d(f(y),f(x))}{d(y,x)}\geq \sup_{1<y}\frac {d(f(y),f(1))}{d(y,1)}\geq \sup_{1>y}1/y=1.$$ But for a contraction $f$ we must have $\sup_{x\ne y} \frac {d(f(y),f(x)}{d(y,x)}<1.$

(III). For $1\leq x<y$ we do have $d(f(x),f(y))<d(x,y),$ and $f$ does have a unique fixed point: $f(1)=1.$  For a function $f$ on a  non-empty complete metric space to have a unique fixed point, it  is sufficient that $f$ be a contraction, but it is not always necessary.

Comment: For an example of a contraction $f$ on a non-complete metric space $X$ such that $f$ has no fixed point, let $X=\Bbb R\setminus \{0\}$ with the usual metric, and let $f(x)=x/2.$

Answer (score 0):

Please formulate your question differently. The fact that you chose C = 1 negates the essence of the definition of contractive functions; hence, I believe it is in order that you revise your definition so that I can become better able to help you. You can't just do these things, man.

Some advice for later: don't make baseless assumptions, man.

Comment: You are not serious, are you? Read the question again, $\cfrac{d(f(x),f(y))}{d(x,y)}<1$ notice the strict inequality, $C\in (0,1)$ so $\cfrac{d(f(x),f(y))}{d(x,y)}\le C<1$

Comment: I'm not even going to bother answering that. Just re-read your definition and YOU let me know what's wrong. Capiche?

Comment: Actually, I'm sorry. I re-read your definition and it seems legit, man. My fault.

Comment: Actually, it's not. I'm 200% convinced you're assuming C=1 and your definition is self-contradictory, man.

Comment: Whatever.......

Comment: Man you're clearly making k dependent on C. There is no C that works for all, man.

Comment: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/contraction.pdf give this a quick read and get back to me in a few. Let me know if you figure it out, man.

Comment: I agree now, I realize Im making C dependent on x,y. But for $C=1/(1+\epsilon)$ this works for all x,y

Comment: Good that your ego stopped getting in the way and you actually got to the first part of your problem. Now, for the second part?

Comment: Don't get me wrong, man. I just want to help you out. But, I want to teach you to fish not just give you the fish you know, man?

Comment: Still there buddy?

Comment: I hope I did not discourage you from investigating the wonders of mathematics, man.

Comment: Is everything okay man?

Comment: Yes yes, I still love math, but here is a tip for you: try to find out what the user is trying to say, and HELP or mention that you are confused by the question. When you say things like "Some advice for later: don't make baseless assumptions, man." is USELESS because I am here to inquire about something I know little about, so what you said was also condescending! I looked at your profile, you seem to have asked questions that were not well received at all, and I am sure you did not do that on purpose, cz you are here to learn, not to criticize. I am sure your intentions are well placed!

Comment: It's disheartening that I came off in a wrong way and I sincerely apologize. Glad you found your answer. This might sound corny but really don't let anyone stop your quest for knowledge. Most people care so much about what others think that they are afraid to ask and inquire and prefer to stick by societal norms and remain clueless rather than have the guts to inquire and admit they do not know something. I salute you for not being like that and having the bravery to learn and explore new horizons. Have a nice life, man.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer man. You have yourself a nice life to ! :)